# Node.js importXlsxSheet with multiple tabs

Tags: smartsheet-api

Using the Node.js importXlsxSheet function to import a workbook into Smartsheet, I've read that the function will only import the first sheet/tab of any given workbook, and I've verified this is the case using a test workbook. However, the "production" workbook I'm trying to upload is failing with a message that "You may only import sheets with up to 5000 rows." This workbook has multiple tabs/sheets and some of them do in fact have more than 5000 rows, but the *first* tab (the one I want to import) has less than 5000 rows.

So what is going on here? If it only imports the first tab of any given workbook, why does it care that other tabs have more than 5000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar behavior to importing an Excel file via the Smartsheet UI in your browser which also does not allow importing an Excel file where any tab has more than 5000 rows. There will be an error that at least one of the tabs has more than 5000 rows and the file can't be imported. I can pass along your feedback that you'd like to see it still import the first tab if that has less than 5000 rows.

Comment: Yeah, that’d be great, thanks Dave. Why is it even looking at other sheets if it only imports the first? A way to choose tabs would be great rather than limiting to just the first.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion. I can add all of this in the feedback I'm collecting on the API. Being able to set which tab to import (provided it is less than 5000 rows) would help in instances when you don't know the state the file was last saved in.